# Should I delete automatically-created files before installing WordPress?

Tags: installation

I'm switching a site from OpenCart to WooCommerce.

I'm trying to figure out what I should delete from `public_html` and what I shouldn't.

Below are the files I'm unsure about. Some of them were there before I installed OpenCart (years ago), but I can't tell which ones.

Is it ok to delete all of them or should I keep some?

```
400.shtml
401.shtml
403.shtml
404.shtml
500.shtml
500.php
cgi-bin (empty folder)
default.html (empty)
error-log
php.ini
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are just index files and you can delete them, Wordpress will add its own index.php file.

php.ini is configuration file for php so you should keep it as it may be of some use. If you get any php related errors you can try deleting it too or we'll need to modify it...